# Video on mousemove

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems while trying to play a video as long as mouse moves. I want it's time to follow mouse, as if the mouse was the time handler.
I have this code. It works fine on Internet Explorer but on Chrome or Mozi time is not fluid, as it has something to do with refreshing times. Video plays with difficult.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mouseX;

    $(document).mousemove( function moveFunc(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    var timV = $(".video").get(0).duration;
    var valV = (timV*mouseX/$(window).width());
    $(".video").get(0).currentTime = valV;

});
</script>
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome stopped firing mousemove events for every mouse position update on the window and document in an attempt to make pages more responsive.
You can fix it by binding your event to something more specific like the video element itself or any wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, but It wouldn't work if user moves on another sections, am I right?